# How to set properties on initial view controller (created in Storyboard) from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I'm doing a call to an API in my AppDelegate.m `didFinishLauncingWithOptions` method. The JSON retrieved will be translated into an `NSArray` of objects. I'd like to set a property of my first view controller to that array so that view controller can use the `latitude` and `longitude` properties of those objects to map out locations.

Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // array retrieved - in actual application, this is an API call and translation
    Obj *object1 = [[Obj alloc] init];
    Obj *object2 = [[Obj alloc] init];
    Obj *object3 = [[Obj alloc] init];

    NSArray *arrayOfObjectsToMap = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, object3, nil];

    // pass object array along to first view controller
    firstController.objectList = arrayOfObjectsToMap;

    return YES;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set properties on the first controller, which was created in Storyboard. The `self.window.rootViewController` of the AppDelegate is of type `UIViewController` and my initial controller is of type `MapViewController` with an `NSArray` property akin to the `objectList`property in the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you import your view controller's header file:

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
```

Then, because you know that your initial view controller is of type MapViewController, just add a cast to the expression:

```
((MapViewController *)firstController).objectList = arrayOfObjectsToMap;
```

To make it more secure you can check if the view controller is really a MapViewController

```
if ([firstController isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]]) {
    ((MapViewController *)firstController).objectList = arrayOfObjectsToMap;
}
```

**Update**

Another option would be a cast right where you assign your `firstController` variable:

```
MapViewController *firstController = (MapViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to pass the data to the view controller using the segue.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailSegue"]){
        ViewControllerB *controller = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.isSomethingEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Please follow the below post for more details.
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: I know that's how you pass data between controllers using segues. I believe this is a different situation. This is the AppDelegate class passing data to the very first controller - no segue between the AppDelegate and the root view controller exists as far as I understand.

Comment: @fishfries you should improve your answer as it doesn't address the OP issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to address the issue by saving the objects created to Core Data (alternatively, I could've used a Singleton or some other storage) and creating my initial view controller to read objects from Core Data.